# I get a object instead of a string while getting that state from the store

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

My reducer looks like :

```
const initialState = {
    name:{}
}

const setNameSlice = createSlice({
    name:"setName",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        setName(state,action){
            state.name = action.payload;
        }
    }
});

export const {setName} = setNameSlice.actions;
```

code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
  nameId : state.setNameReducer.name
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setName: (name) => dispatch(setName(name))
})
```

The dispatch function that is called takes in some name and stores it correctly(by checking the devtool) , the state now looks like `setNameReducer : {name : "Something"}`  . But, Once i console.log that value `console.log(this.props.nameId)` i get `state name {}__proto__: Object` in the log.

Comment: Don't need return ?

Comment: Where ? So, first part of the code is to create a reducer which i don't think need a return. Then, 2nd part is to get the value in the store and send a value to store.. which also doesn't need a return i guess.. I'm using reduxtoolkit

Comment: The way I see it, the value of `this.props.nameId` should be an Object _before_ you have dispatched a state change. This is because you are assigning the initial value of your setNameSlice's `name` property to an empty Object (`{}`). This value should become a String _after_ you have called `setName("Something")` from your connected component.

Comment: I actually fix the issue. The problem was I `console.log(this.props.nameId)` inside `componentDidMount` was runs only after the first render. By console logging it inside the render() function worked !